# log4net Configuration Section for NUnit Test Project

Tags: .net, configuration, nunit, log4net

I am running NUnit with the project named AssemblyTest.nunit. The test calls another assembly which uses the log4net assembly. This is using nunit version 2.4.3 with the .net 2.0 framework.

In TestFixtureSetup I am calling log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure( ) and am getting the following error:

```
System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Configuration system failed to initialize ---> System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Unrecognized configuration section log4net. (C:\path\to\assembly.dll.config line 7)
```

Is there a way to fix this without renaming the config file to 'AssemblyTest.config'?

Comment: I'm not familiar with .NET but there is nothing in the error that implies to me at least that this has anything to do with the name of the config file. It looks to me more like there is a problem with line 7 <i>in</i> your config file.

Comment: Yeah, that's why I asked the question. The config file line works with the file named by the nunit project name and exactly the same text. Thanks for the point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a separate config file for log4net with root element log4net.

In TestFixtureSetup create a FileInfo object for this config file and give it as argument to log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure( ).

Answer (score 11):

I had the same problem because I forget to add the *log4net* definition in the *configSections* element.

So, if you want to put *log4net*-elements into the app.config, you need to include the *configSections* element (which tells where *log4net*-elements are defined) at the top of the config file.

Try it like this:

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" />
  </configSections>
  <log4net>
  ...
  </log4net>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I had this problem too with the Visual Studio test system

Answer (score 7):

I don't know why you guys are trapped in config files, for nunit if you like to see logs running in Text Output window in nunit test runner all you need to do is following line of code,

```
BasicConfigurator.Configure();
```

best point add this line is the constructor of Test class

e.g.

```
[TestFixture]
    public class MyTest
    {
        log4net.ILog log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(MyTest));

        public MyTest()
        {
            BasicConfigurator.Configure();
        }

        [SetUp]
        public void SetUp()
        {
           log.Debug(">SetUp");               
        }

        [TearDown]
        public void TearDown()
        {
            log.Debug(">TearDown");
        }

        [Test]
        public void TestNothing()
        {
            log.Debug(">TestNothing");
        }
    }
```

Comment: This turned all of my log statements into output in the unit test and didn't require redoing anything the application actually used. +1 for no config file! Perfect!

Comment: Calling BasicConfigurator.Configure() does not work for me. Anyone else have similar issues?