# log4net and nunit tests, most basic example

Tags: c#, tdd, nunit, log4net

I want to try log some app messages from my app. In this very situation I just want to force nunit to work with log4net. I found some example here http://www.ofconsulting.com/PublicPortal/ofc-tech-blog/92-configure-log4net-with-nunit.html.

log4net is confugured in app.config like this:

```xml
<configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler,Log4net"/>
  </configSections>

<log4net>
    <root>
      <level value="DEBUG" />
      <appender-ref ref="LogFileAppender" />
    </root>
    <appender name="LogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender" >
      <param name="File" value="log.txt" />
      <param name="AppendToFile" value="true" />
      <rollingStyle value="Size" />
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
      <maximumFileSize value="10MB" />
      <staticLogFileName value="true" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%-5p%d{yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss} – %m%n" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
  </log4net>
```

**And in my test code is following**

```
[TestFixture]
class DomainTests
{
    protected static readonly ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(DomainTests));
    public void LoggingTests()
    {            
        log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure(); 
    }

    [Test]
    public void BasicLogTest()
    {
        log.Error("write my log entry already");
    }
```

My test is passed but nothing is written inside log.txt file. What am I doing wrong?
I just want to make it as simple as possible to store messages like entering an application, exit application. Regards.

Comment: Does Log4Net work normally?  The reason I ask is that I want to know whether we need to go through your loading up of Log4Net...

Comment: Also, to save you typing our your class name every time I use this to copy/paste my log between classes:

private static readonly ILog Logger = LogManager.GetLogger(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);

Comment: how do you mean does it work normally ?:) I'm added log4net reference to my test project and rest of the code is posted here, no error message given in running test or building prj.

Comment: @Vijay, I need some concrete example of logging with nunit and app.config, if you have something already to examine it would be great.

Comment: where is this log.txt located? I have copied your code and specified c:\log.txt in app.config then it works perfect.Try specifying the full path for log.txt

Comment: Why are you testing logging? What benefit does that provide to test a 3rd party library?

Comment: @tsells just to make I'm configured properly log4net, and to move further from that.

Comment: @LukeHutton & vijay when I add comment to a question I am unable to go back to that question. Since I am new, please help me understand how to go back to a commented question from my profile. I do see all my answered questions in my profile.

Comment: @Esen You can do this by going to your User Profile and then Activity tab. There may be other ways but I would check meta.stackoverflow.com, as most likely answered there.

Comment: @LukeHutton Thank you for the instruction. Will leave comment instead of answer just to track it back.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My best guess would be for you to do something like this:

```
[TestFixture]
class DomainTests
{
    protected static readonly ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(DomainTests));
    public void LoggingTests()
    {            
        log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure(); 
    }

    [Test]
    public void BasicLogTest()
    {
        log.Error("write my log entry already");
    }

    [SetUp]
    RunBeforeAnyTests()
    {
        BasicConfigurator.Configure();
    }

    [TearDown]
    RunAfterAnyTests()
    {
        // ...
    }
```

I'd also use the Log4Net.config file rather than the app.config file, it just seems cleaner. Here's an example log4net.config file:

```xml
<log4net>
  <!-- A1 is set to be a LogFileAppender -->
  <appender name="LogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender, log4net" >
    <param name="File" value="C:\logging\log.txt" />
    <file value="c:\logging\Main" />
    <appendToFile value="true" />
    <datePattern value="yyyyMMdd'.log'" />
    <rollingStyle value="Composite" />
    <staticLogFileName value="false" />
    <maxSizeRollBackups value="-1" />
    <maximumFileSize value="500MB" />

    <!-- A1 uses PatternLayout -->
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger - %message%newline" />
    </layout>
  </appender>
  <!-- Set root logger level to DEBUG and its only appender to LogFileAppender -->
  <root>
    <!--<level value="OFF" />-->
    <!--<level value="FATAL" />-->
    <!--<level value="ERROR" />-->
    <!--<level value="WARN" />-->
    <!--<level value="INFO" />-->
    <level value="DEBUG" />
    <!--<level value="ALL" />-->
    <appender-ref ref="LogFileAppender" />
  </root>
</log4net>
```

Answer (score 23):

The problem is that the NUnit test runner (when run from resharper in visual studio) runs the test from another folder (it shadow copies the test assembly), so the xml configuration is not available at that point unless you specify the full config path.

You could of course use the basic configuration and specify the logging configuration in code, like:

```
log4net.Config.BasicConfigurator.Configure(
  new log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender {
    Layout = new log4net.Layout.SimpleLayout()});
```

You should see the log output in the test output after that.

Answer (score 6):

As long as I know and used log4net with nunit, **I have never used any config file**, you just need to add following line in test class constructor

```
BasicConfigurator.Configure();
```

[here is the full answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159856/log4net-configuration-section-for-nunit-test-project/19672646#19672646) if you like to see the sample test class

Answer (score 3):

You can adjust your unit test to check for the file itself (instead of manual inspection). Notice the file path stored in environment variables. This works on TeamCity test runners as well (no need to hard code a path).

Config:

```xml
<log4net>
  <appender name="RollingLogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
    <file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="%env{ALLUSERSPROFILE}\test.log" />
    <appendToFile value="true" />
    <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
    <maximumFileSize value="10MB" />
    <rollingStyle value="Size" />
    <staticLogFileName value="true" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger - %message%newline" />
    </layout>
  </appender>
  <root>
    <level value="INFO" />
    <appender-ref ref="RollingLogFileAppender" />
  </root>
</log4net>
```

Code:

```
private string _expectedFile;

[SetUp]
public void SetUp()
{
    _expectedFile = Path.Combine(
        Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ALLUSERSPROFILE"),
        "test.log");

    if (File.Exists(_expectedFile))
        File.Delete(_expectedFile);

    XmlConfigurator.Configure();
}

[Test] public void GivenLog4NetFileAppender_WhenLogInfoStringWithLog4Net_ThenWritesToDisk()
{
    ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof (LoggingIntegrationTests));
    log.Info("Message from test");

    LogManager.Shutdown();

    Assert.That(File.ReadAllText(_expectedFile),
                Is.StringContaining("Message from test"));
}
```